# Golang choice number from slice/array with given probability

Tags: go, probability

Hello i'm looking for a way to choose number from array/slice with given probability vector, for example like this:
We have data [0,1,2] and probability vector[0.2,0.5,0.3]
so we choose 0 with probability 0.2, 1 with probability 0.5 and 2 with probability 0.3
in python i would use numpy.random.choice . but i don't know how to do it in Go
i can use random from 0-100 and then with if's make something like if number is 0-20 then its 0 and same way for others. But i think there is better way to do it and more generic to do it as function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is simply to compute the cdf from the given probabilities (pdf) and then find the correct bucket:

```
func sample(cdf []float32) int {
    r := rand.Float32()

    bucket := 0
    for r > cdf[bucket] {
        bucket++
    }
    return bucket
}
```

Getting the cdf is done by

```
func main() {
    // probability density function
    pdf := []float32{0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1}

    // get cdf
    cdf := []float32{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    cdf[0] = pdf[0]
    for i := 1; i < 4; i++ {
        cdf[i] = cdf[i-1] + pdf[i]
    }

    // test sampling with 100 samples
    samples := []float32{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        samples[sample(cdf)]++
    }

    // normalize
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        samples[i] /= 100.
    }

    fmt.Println(samples)
    fmt.Println(pdf)

}
```

Full example:
https://play.golang.org/p/ceZx1EiYW3l

The output of `sample` follows the given probabilities:

```
samples: [0.33 0.43 0.15 0.09]
pdf: [0.3 0.4 0.2 0.1]
```